# Error Creating a database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to create a database with a php file but I don't know why when i run it, it displays this error: "**Error: CREATE TABLE contaclick ( id int(20) NOT NULL auto_increment, link varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', count int(20) NOT NULL default '0', PRIMARY KEY (id) ) TYPE=MyISAM;**"
Someone knows how to fix it?

my code in php is this:

```
<?
$login = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$database = "xxx";

$db = mysql_connect("xxx", $login, $password) or die ("Errore!");
mysql_select_db($database, $db);

$sql = "CREATE TABLE contaclick (
id int(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
link varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
count int(20) NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) TYPE=MyISAM;";

@mysql_query($sql) or die("Errore: $sql");

$sql = "INSERT INTO contaclick VALUES('', 'https://www.mywebsite.com/', '0')";
@mysql_query($sql) or die("Errore: $sql");
?>
```

Comment: @Nick `COUNT` isn't a reserved word https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-C

Comment: you need to get the real errors here, you're not doing that

Comment: You should at least be using mysqli

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: You should also avoid using the ancient MyISAM database engine. InnoDB is the safe default these days.

Comment: **WARNING**: Using the error-suppressing `@` operator obscures problems with your code and makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated. That's a tool of last resort and should only be used in exceptional circumstances. You should display an error message for the user, log a problem, initiate some kind of retry, or all of these things in conjunction.

Comment: This sort of code suggests you're learning from a resource that is *at least* ten years out of date, and probably more. Tutorials don't have a "best before" date, but they really should. Look for those that use PDO as a baseline, especially those with prepared statements and placeholder values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TYPE` is deprecated, use `ENGINE` instead

```
CREATE TABLE contaclick ( id int(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 link varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
 count int(20) NOT NULL default '0', PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE = MyISAM
```

Comment: Happy to help (: